# Inserting rows to table variable using recursive table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnList](@id INT, @parent INT) RETURNS @res TABLE(
    [id] INT,
    [parent] INT,
    [parent_parent] INT,
    [amount] FLOAT,
    [cost] FLOAT,
    [table] VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @res
    SELECT * FROM SomeTable

    --Here I want to insert some more values

    INSERT INTO @res
    SELECT dbo.fnList(Results.id, Results.parent)
    FROM @res Results WHERE Results.[table] = 'SomeValue' AND Results.parent = @id

END
```

The function is recursive. When I call the function I get the error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.fnList", or the name is ambiguous.

The trouble is in the last part, after the comment. I want to insert multiple rows in @res. In res there are records with table = 'SomeValue' and 'OtherValue'. For the first values I want to call the function again. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`dbo.fnList` is a table-valued function. You are calling it within itself as if it were a scalar function. i.e.

`SELECT dbo.fnList(Results.id, Results.parent)`

as opposed to the correct syntax of:

`SELECT * FROM dbo.fnList(Results.id, Results.parent)`

Of course the above would not work as `Results` is itself a table alias and not an integer. So you'd need a cursor to loop through the results and call dbo.fnList.

Even if you could get the syntax corrected however surely you are quickly going to run into problems with the nesting level maximum of 32?

> User-defined functions can be nested; that is, one user-defined
>   function can call another. The nesting level is incremented when the
>   called function starts execution, and decremented when the called
>   function finishes execution. User-defined functions can be nested up
>   to 32 levels. Exceeding the maximum levels of nesting causes the whole
>   calling function chain to fail.

Looks like you are either going to have to add a lot of looping into the function or re-think the solution.